# Scaled central t distribution

Tags: distributions, t-distribution

My question is related to [**THIS POST.**](http://bayesfactor.blogspot.com/2014/02/bayes-factor-t-tests-part-1.html) The author says if we scale a central t-distribution with **9 df** by `1/sqrt(10)`, we get something like the picture below (**my question is:** how we have scaled the t-distribution to get this?)

**In other words**, we have have applied the `1/sqrt(10)` to what?

(e.g., **using R**, where should `1/sqrt(10)` be applied in `curve(dt(x,df=9), -3,3)`)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean is that they are using [location-scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family) version of $t$ distribution, so if $f$ is a probability density of $t$ distribution, and $F$ is a cumulative distribution function, then $f(\tfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma})/\sigma$ and $F(\tfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ are location-scale pdf and cdf.

This leads to the following plot:

```r
curve(dt(x*sqrt(10), df = 9)*sqrt(10), -2, 3) # location = 0, scale = 1/sqrt(10)
```

[image: Location-scale t distribution example]

If you want it implemented as a single function, it is implemented in [extraDistr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/extraDistr/versions/1.8.3/topics/NonStandardT) library.

Comment: @parvinkarimi but this code is *not* related to t distribution parameterized by scale but to standard noncentral t.

Comment: Moreover I don't see what do you mean and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: The code is given in my answer. Sorry but it is not clear for me what are you asking?

Comment: First, this is not related to the initial question, so maybe you should ask a new one? Second, why would you assume that different data and different distributions return the same probabilities..?