# What is the scaled t distribution?

Tags: t-distribution

Where can I find reading material on the "scaled t distribution"? Wiki does not help

What is it? How is it different than the t-distribution?

Comment: Does this help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/260173/1390

Comment: Do you have a reference that can provide more context?  It seems likely your source was referring merely to a variable which, when rescaled, follows a t-distribution.